# PHP getting elements from an array stored in mySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mySQL table which has a field where I keep my arrays in it. So in the table field I have this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"XXX1";i:1;s:10:"XXX2";}
```

I am using this code snippet in PHP to get the field value.

```
$getCodes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar='$barID'");
while($codeRow = mysql_fetch_array($getCodes))
{
  $code = $codeRow['codes'];
}
```

When I echo the $code, it prints the full array. How can I print each element on a new line or how can I access specific elements?

Comment: It is not a good idea to store arrays in a single field. Take a look at [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: are you storing it in a serialize format? or someother

Comment: @MostyMostacho - Sometimes there are good reasons to store arrays in a single field.  It depends on circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$code = unserialize($codeRow['codes']);
```